# How to get the name of the object being passed to a function within the function?

Tags: python

I'm taking machine learning and see myself peeking at the data before building models and so on. I want to have a function to give me the top N sample of the data.
Let say I have function sample_data defined like this:

```
"""print top N of the data
"""
def sample_data (data_name, n):
    print ('{}: {}'.format(name_of_the_data_being_passed_to_parameter_data_name, data_name[:n]))
```

I have tried

```
eval()
```

but it didn't work.

I also tried

```
.__code__.co_varnames
```

but it returns the parameter names of the function itself, NOT the object being passed.

Is there a way to achieve this? I'm using python 2.7 to match with the class environment.

btw, the object I want to view is pickle file .pkl

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: It depends on the type of object.

When you do something like `x=1`, `x` is a simple type that refers to a value that exists at a certain point in memory. It, itself does not hold a reference to its own name.

However, you can get around this by creating functions and classes.
I'm not overly familiar with python2, but at least in python3 you can call `.__name__` on functions and classes.

e.g:

```py
class A:
  pass

def b(self):
  pass
```

`A.__name__` would equal `'A'` and `b.__name__` would equal `b`.

Another way to create something like this is to create your own type. Again, I'm not sure if this works in python2, but in python3 you can do something like: `x = type('a', (), {})` and then `x.__name__` would equal `'a'`.

Edit:
A class object will have a `__name__` attribute, but once it has been instantiated, that attribute would no longer exist. To get around this, you would need to call `.__class__` before `.__name__`.

Comment: Classes have a ```__name__``` attribute but instances of most class objects do not, so it won't help to identify data objects passed to a function. (in your example, if ```a = A()```, ```a``` does not have a ```__name__```).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I'll edit my post.